# Подскажите,как вырежать из background круг и вставить туда лого?

Tags: html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно сверстать макет,так как не работал с такой темой(лого в кругу на другом background).Хотел бы попросить помощи,как бы Вы решили данную проблему.

Comment: Обычный `<div>` с `border-radius: 50%` и `background-color: #FFF;`.

Comment: Спасибо,попробую

Answer (score 1):

Вложить в `<div>`, с помощью `border-radius: 50%;` получить круг, с помощью `background-color` -- нужный цвет фона:

```css
#back {
  background-color: green;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 25px;
}

#logo {
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml, %3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' aria-hidden='true' width='18' height='18' viewBox='0 0 18 18'%3E%3Cpath d='M15 2V1H3v1H0v4c0 1.6 1.4 3 3 3v1c.4 1.5 3 2.6 5 3v2H5s-1 1.5-1 2h10c0-.4-1-2-1-2h-3v-2c2-.4 4.6-1.5 5-3V9c1.6-.2 3-1.4 3-3V2h-3ZM3 7c-.5 0-1-.5-1-1V4h1v3Zm8.4 2.5L9 8 6.6 9.4l1-2.7L5 5h3l1-2.7L10 5h2.8l-2.3 1.8 1 2.7h-.1ZM16 6c0 .5-.5 1-1 1V4h1v2Z'%3E%3C/path%3E%3C/svg%3E");
}
```

```html
<div id="back">
  <div id="logo"></div>
</div>
```